# Can't upload user picture

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-8

I want to upload an image for a simply user on the default form and I get the following error :

> "The file could not be uploaded."

I have tried with all types of file formats.

I also checked the rights to the directory :

> sites/default/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the Database log module and check the log,
also check the permission of  `sites/default/files`

And Also check the temporary directory has been set up to a correct place.

Take a look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30113/configuring-the-temporary-directory could help you.